# Vuex ORM model constructor issue on insert

Tags: vuex-orm

I have the following model:

```
import { Model } from '@vuex-orm/core'

export class User extends Model {
    static entity = 'users'

    static fields () {
        return {
            id: this.attr(null),
            name: this.attr('')
        }
    }
}
```

and when I try to do this:

```
User.insert({
    data: { id: 1, name: 'John' }
})
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Class constructor User cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

Any idea what is the problem? This code is from the documentation, so I'm confused a little bit.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on my end.

Answer (score 0):

as I can see you are missing the registration of the model in the database at the beginning of the application.

You have to implement your vuex store with the corresponding plugin
 EXAMPLE:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VuexORM from '@vuex-orm/core'
import User from '@/models/User'
import Post from '@/models/Post'

Vue.use(Vuex)

// Create a new instance of Database.
const database = new VuexORM.Database()

// Register Models to Database.
database.register(User)
database.register(Post)

// Create Vuex Store and register database through Vuex ORM.
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  plugins: [VuexORM.install(database)]
})

export default store
```

[You now have good documentation in this regard](https://vuex-orm.github.io/vuex-orm/guide/prologue/getting-started.html#register-models-to-vuex)

I hope I have helped you, greetings